# Handle Circular redirect using Rest Assured

Tags: redirect, apache-httpclient-4.x, rest-assured

I am trying to send request GET method for one of our product API. URL needs site minder authentication and redirects to requested target.

I can able to get response for GET by setting circular redirect to true using apache http client. Code looks like this

```
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpGet get = new HttpGet(url);
    client.getParams().setParameter(ClientPNames.ALLOW_CIRCULAR_REDIRECTS, true);
    get.setHeader("Authorization", "Basic "+encodedAuth );
    HttpResponse response = c.execute(get);
```

How do i get this work with Rest Assured library ?

Tried below but getting

> Caused by: org.apache.http.client.CircularRedirectException: Circular redirect to

Code :

```
`//RestAssuredConfig.config().getRedirectConfig().followRedirects(true).allowCircularRedirects(true);`
RestAssuredConfig.newConfig().getHttpClientConfig().setParam("http.protocol.allow-circular-redirects", true);
    Response r = given().header("Authorization", "Basic " + encodedAuth).get(
            URL);
```

Answer (score 2):

`RestAssuredConfig` is [immutable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object) so you probably should do something like this:

```
RestAssured.config = RestAssured.config().httpClientConfig(httpClientConfig().setParam("http.protocol.allow-circular-redirects", true));
```

This will apply the configuration of all requests. If you only want to apply this for a single or selected requests you can do like this (I'm trowing in preemptive basic auth here as well so that you don't manually have to set the Authorization header):

```
RestAssuredConfig cfg = RestAssuredConfig.newConfig().httpClientConfig(httpClientConfig().setParam("http.protocol.allow-circular-redirects", true));
Response r = given().config(cfg).auth().preemptive().basic("username", "password").get(URL);
```

There's also a [redirect DSL](https://github.com/jayway/rest-assured/wiki/Usage#redirect-dsl) that simplifies this. So you probably ought to do something like this instead of setting the property manually:

```
Response r = 
given().
        redirects().allowCircular(true).
        auth().preemptive().basic("username", "password").
when().
        get(URL);
```